# Installing Pinax, where is my deployment folder?

Tags: django, deployment, pinax

I'm trying to set up Pinax and I'm new to everything involved (Django, Pinax, webservers, etc). I'm following http://pinax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gettingstarted.html

When I generate a project using:

```
(mysite-env)$ pinax-admin setup_project -b basic mysite
```

The directory structure I get is:

```
apps      __init__.py   manage.py     settings.pyc  urls.py
dev.db    __init__.pyc  requirements  static        urls.pyc
fixtures  locale        settings.py   templates     wsgi.py
```

Which as far as I can tell is missing the **deployment** folder (when you compare to the directory structure shown here : http://pinax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/starterprojects.html). It doesn't seem to be effecting anything yet, but it makes me nervous. What is going on and is the fact I'm missing the deployment folder going to cause problems in the future?

I'm running Ubuntu and using python 2.7. I had the same behaviour with Windows 7, python 2.6

Thanks!

Comment: The `wsgi.py` seems to have been moved to the project root folder instead of the `deploy` sub-folder.  The doc could be out of date.

Comment: Also, if you are using django 1.4, project templates have made pinax starter projects obsolete. You might consider looking at the new django way of doing things here https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Django versions have made the old pinax pretty much useless. Now Django supports project templates and Pinax is separated into several smaller projects regarding starter projects (such as [pinax-project-account](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account)) and apps (such as [django-user-account](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts)).

The current way to use pinax is to choose a starter project, and then running something like:

`$ django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account/zipball/master <project_name>`

and then install requirements:

`$ pip install -r requirements.txt`

This will create a new Django project using the starter-project as a template, which already includes a few apps (like django-user-account) and templates (with bootstrap!). The project is ready to run, and already includes a bunch of functionality (like user registration, login and management).

Also, Django has changed the project directory structure a bit, so now it doesn't really look like that anymore.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the additional information and that makes a lot of sense. I'm already a good ways in to doing it the "wrong" way, so here's hoping deployment will work...